# Use of 'extern' keyword while defining the variable

Tags: c, variables, extern

After seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c/1433387#1433387) answer
I have this doubt.
In my project,
I have seen some extern variables declared and defined like below:

***file1.h***

```
extern int a;
```

***file1.c***

```
extern int a=10;
```

But in the link I mentioned it says that in the c file it should be defined like:

```
int a = 10;
```

Does adding `extern` key word during the definition too has any purpose/meaning.
Or does it matter by the way?

Comment: The question that you reference is a C question. Did you mean to tag this as C++ as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not change the meaning. `extern` only makes sense when you *declare* a variable. *Defining* a variable with `extern` is the same because all global variables that are not marked `static` are symbols visible to the linker by default.

Note that if you didn't want to initialise the variable, that is, not having the part `= 10`, the compiler will assume that `extern int a` is always a *declaration* and not a *definition*. In the same sense, having `int a` globally is always a *definition* and not just a *declaration*.

Comment: `int a` (at file scope) is a tentative definition in C, a definition in C++ and always a declaration. I think you might have meant: "...always a definition and not _just_ a declaration".

Comment: The answer is actually incorrect.  All non-`const` variables at namespace scope that are not marked `static` are visible to the linker (have external linkage).  `const` variables have internal linkage (not visible to the linker) unless marked `extern` somewhere.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Is this true in C? I thought it was only C++.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Only C++.  I missed the fact that this was tagged for both languages---this is one point where C and C++ differ.

Answer (score 3):

It depends.  In this case, it makes no difference, but it can.

There are two issues here: definition vs. just declaration, and linkage. 
And C++ doesn't handle them in an orthogonal manner.  In C++, the
declaration of a variable or a reference is a definition if and only if
neither the `extern` keyword nor an initialization are present.  (Note
that the rules are different for functions, types and templates.)  So:

```
extern int a;       //  not a definition
int a;              //  definition
extern int a = 42;  //  definition
int a = 42;         //  definition
```

The rules say you must have exactly one definition, so you put a
definition in a source file, and the declaration in a header.

With regards to linkage, a symbol declared as a variable or a reference
has external linkage if it is declared at namespace scope, is not
declared `static`, and is either not `const` (nor `constexpr` in C++11)
or has been declared `extern`.  The fact that `const` can give a
variable internal linkage occasionally means that the `extern` is
necessary:

```
int const a = 42;           //  internal linkage
extern int const a = 42;    //  external linkage
```

Note that the `extern` doesn't have to be on the same declaration:

```
extern int const a;         //  declaration, in header...
int const a = 42;           //  external linkage, because of
                            //  previous extern
```

Still, I've occasionally needed the `extern`; typically because I want
to use a local constant to instantiate a template.  (This is only an
issue if the template parameter takes a pointer or a reference.  You can
instantiate a template with an `int` parameter with an `int const a =
42;`, because the template is instantiated with the value 42, and not
the variable `a`.)