# Difference between extern int a; extern int a=42;

Tags: c

While I was reading the answers of [Use of 'extern' keyword while defining the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606909/use-of-extern-keyword-while-defining-the-variable)

One of the user answered these way

```
 extern int a;       //  not a definition 
 extern int a = 42;  //  definition
```

I was expecting both are not definitions but declarations. I was thinking Both statements says that the variable is defined outside the function and we have to use extern keyword  to use it. is this a mistake by him or is it really a definition ?
I know that

```
extern int a; // variable is already defined but its outside the function
extern int a=42 ; //I guess a variable is assigned a value but not a definition
```

but these statement

```
extern int a = 42; // user said its a definition and now i got  confused
```

Please clear me with these.

Comment: The declarations being discussed in the linked questions are all assumed to be file scoped declarations, not function scoped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever initialisation is attempted, the statement becomes a *definition*, no matter that `extern` is used. The `extern` keyword is redundant in such a case because, by default, symbols not marked `static` already have external linkage.

It doesn't make sense to *declare* an external variable and set its initial value in the current compilation unit, that's a contradiction.

Comment: wow ! i did not know that c is really a language with a miracles binded in it

Comment: so You mean extern int a = 42 ; is nothing but int a = 42 ? right

Comment: okay I have got some thoughts on my mind after seeing you answer let me try it on my compiler and update my question if i have any issues with that. but thanks !

Answer (score 5):

`extern int a;` is a declaration. It does not allocate space for storing a.

`extern int a = 42;` is a definition. It allocates space to store the int value a and assigns it the value 42.

Answer (score 0):

here the variables are declared inside the main() function where its definition was defined outside in the global declaration section

```
extern int a; //This is a declaration

extern int a=42; //This is a definition
```