# C Undefined reference

Tags: c, header-files, resource-files

I got some problem with the following codes particularly in header.c where i can't access the extern int x variable in header.h... Why? Does extern variable in .h not global? How can i use this on other files?

===header.h===

```
#ifndef HDR_H
#define HDR_H

extern int x;
void function();

#endif
```

===header.c===

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

void function()
{
    printf("%d", x); //****undefined reference to x, why?****
}
```

===sample.c===

```
int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    function();
    printf("\n%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possibly just remove the `int` before `x` in your main function. this would prevent a new local variable being created in the main function with the same name as the global variable

Comment: (removed; accidentally added comment)

Comment: See also more info about the extern int in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610321/difference-between-extern-int-a-extern-int-a-42][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610321/difference-between-extern-int-a-extern-int-a-42

Answer (score 9):

The declaration

```
extern int x;
```

tells the compiler that in some source file there will be a *global* variable named `x`. However, in the `main` function you declare a *local* variable `x`. Move that declaration outside of `main` to make it global.

Answer (score 3):

The `extern` keyword say the variable exists but does not create it. The compiler expects that another module will have a global variable with that name, and the linker will do the right thing to join them up.

You need to change `sample.c` like this:

```
/* x is a global exported from sample.c */
int x = 1;

int main()
{
    function();
    printf("\n%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`extern` declares a variable, but does not define it. It basically tells the compiler there is a definition for `x` somewhere else. To fix add the following to `header.c` (or some other `.c` file but *only* one `.c` file):

```
int x;
```

Note that in `main()` the local variable `x` will hide the global variable `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed `extern int x;` means `x` will be defined in another place/translation unit.

The compiler expects to find a definition of `x` in the global scope somewherelse.

Answer (score 0):

I would reorganise/modify your code like this and get rid of header.c

===sample.h===

```
#ifndef SAMPLE_H
#define SAMPLE_H

extern int x;
void function();

#endif
```

===sample.c===

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sample.h"

int x;

void function()
{
    printf("%d", x);
}

int main()
{
    x = 1;
    function();
    printf("\n%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```